# How to get notified in SwiftUI when UIKit UIViewController viewDidLoad finished

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, uikit

I have a `UIViewController` working fine in `SwiftUI` with the below code.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

final class RTCVideoViewController: UIViewController {
  
  var previewView: RTCEAGLVideoView!
  var videoTrack: RTCVideoTrack!
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    previewView = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))
    previewView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    view.addSubview(previewView)
    
    do {
      videoTrack = try MediaCapturer.shared.createVideoTrack(videoView: previewView)
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }
  }
}

extension RTCVideoViewController : UIViewControllerRepresentable{
  public typealias UIViewControllerType = RTCVideoViewController
  
  public func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<RTCVideoViewController>) -> RTCVideoViewController {
    return RTCVideoViewController()
  }
  
  public func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: RTCVideoViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<RTCVideoViewController>) {
  }
}
```

In SwiftUI view.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct LiveView: View {
  
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: LiveViewModel
  
  init(viewModel: LiveViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    return ZStack {
      RTCVideoViewController()
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
  }
}
```

So far everything works fine but I need the `RTCVideoTrack` when created to pass it to the `LiveViewModel`.

Any ideas what pattern I could implement to get notified when viewDidLoad finished or `RTCVideoTrack` passed to the `LiveViewModel`?

Answer (score 0):

I changed a bit the code, it was close but simplified more.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct RTCVideoViewController : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  var viewModel: LiveViewModel

  
  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
      UIViewController()
  }
  
  func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
    print("HostBroadcastViewController:updateUIViewController")
    let previewView = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))
    previewView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    viewController.view.addSubview(previewView)
    
    do {
      let videoTrack = try MediaCapturer.shared.createVideoTrack(videoView: previewView)
      self.viewModel.videoTrack = videoTrack
    }
    catch {
      print("ERROR getting RTCVideoTrack")
    }
  }
}
```

And in SwiftUI init the `RTCVideoViewController` with `RTCVideoViewController(viewModel: self.viewModel)` where ViewModel passed in view from parent.